# SwipeListView by 47degree: swipe first item programmatically

Tags: android, listview, swipe

I would like to swipe the first item on the [SwipeListView](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview) on `Activity` start up to show the user that the `SwipeListView` is swipe-able.

How can I perform this action programmatically with this UI element?

### Update

I tried to use the

```
swipeListView.openAnimate(position)
```

that was proposed here in the answer, but for some reason even after I populate the adapter with data-items... when I debug and reach this code section the swipeListView doesn't see item in it, and fails with `NullPointerException`.

### Update 2

Well, I realized that the reason there were no items in the adapter because it's not yet created in `onCreate`, so I moved this code to method:

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){}
```

of my activity, now it runs but still fails on the following method of the `SwipeListView` library:

```
 private void resetCell() {
    if (downPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        if (swipeCurrentAction == SwipeListView.SWIPE_ACTION_CHOICE) {
            backView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        frontView.setClickable(opened.get(downPosition));
        frontView.setLongClickable(opened.get(downPosition));
        frontView = null;
        backView = null;
        downPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;
    }
}
```

The reason for this is that when this method is running the `frontView` object is never set and those it null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually went and recreated the used animation in the library just for the instance of the Showcase, so what I did was:

```
private void generateRevealAnimate(final View view) {
    animate(view)
    .translationX(-520)
    .setDuration(500)
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {}
    }); 
}

private void generateCloseAnimate(final View view) {
    animate(view)
    .translationX(0)
    .setDuration(500)
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {}
    });
}
```

And then just run them one after another on the desired view:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        generateRevealAnimate(firstFrontView); 
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                generateCloseAnimate(firstFrontView);  
            }
        }, 1400);
    }
}, 1400);
```

Answer (score 1):

For openining the item you should use

```
swipeListView.openAnimate(position)
```

For closing the item you can use on of this:

```
swipeListView.closeAnimate(position);
swipeListView.closeOpenedItems();
```

Here is some code from working project:

```
private BaseSwipeListViewListener albumsLIstener = new BaseSwipeListViewListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClickFrontView(int position) {
        if (albumsListsView.isOpened(position)) {
            albumsListsView.closeAnimate(position);
        } else albumsListsView.openAnimate(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClickBackView(int position) {
        if (albumsListsView.isOpened(position)) {
            albumsListsView.closeAnimate(position);
        } else albumsListsView.openAnimate(position);
    }
};
```

Comment: I tried this code and for some reason I get a nullPointerexception on the openAnimate method. I will keep checking, Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you had a null pointer inside SwipeListView - check position which you put to method. also it can be bug inside listview.

Comment: Yeah I'm still checking this, If will let you know what I have found.

Comment: The item is not null, for some reason I'm getting nullpointerexception on this line: openAnimate(swipeListView.getChildAt(position - swipeListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()).findViewById(swipeFrontView), position); of the SwipeListViewTouchListener.

Comment: Its wrong. You should set SwipeListViewListener to SwipeListView and use position from method onClickFrontView or onClickBackView. Read about what getChildAt() and getFirstVisiblePosition() returns.

Comment: But I don't want to click on those view, I want the list to appear with the first item swiped as the activity start up.

Comment: You should simple call swipeListView.openAnimate(0)

Answer (score 1):

Check the source code!

[SwipeListViewTouchListener](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/blob/master/swipelistview/src/com/fortysevendeg/swipelistview/SwipeListViewTouchListener.java) sets the frontView. `setFrontView()` is only being called in case of on touch down event. So either you somehow fake a touch event for this view or you fork the library and update it to your needs.